# Unknown segfault while using threads for vector members

Tags: c++, multithreading, loops, reference, segmentation-fault

I am using threads to find the cheapest Edge from every component(graph) from vector. It's implementation of boruvka's algorithm.

Code is here:

```
void findPath(const Graph &component, Edge &edge) {
    if (component.edges.size()<1 || !component.edges.front().weight)return;
    int min = component.edges.front().weight;
    edge = component.edges.front();
    for (Edge e: component.edges) {
        if (e.weight < min) {
            min = e.weight;
            edge = e;
        }
    }
}

Graph boruvkaParalel(Graph *graph) {
Graph mst;
std::vector<Graph> components;
for (int i = 0; i < graph->nodes.size(); ++i) {
    Graph a;
    addEdges(&a, getEdgesForNode(graph->nodes[i], graph));
    a.nodes.push_back(graph->nodes[i]);
    components.push_back(a);
}

while (components.size() > 1) {
Graph toCollapse;
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
std::vector<Edge> minEdges;

for (auto &g: components) {
    minEdges.push_back({});
}

std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst);

for (size_t i=0; i<components.size(); ++i) {
    threads.emplace_back([&]{findPath(components[i], minEdges[i]);});
}

for (auto &i : threads) {
    i.join();
}
for (Edge edge:minEdges) {
    if (!contains(mst, edge) && edge.weight != 0) {
        addEdge(&mst, edge.n1, edge.n2, edge.weight);
        addEdge(&toCollapse, edge.n1, edge.n2, edge.weight);
    }
}
...
//collapse components based on choosen edges
...
}
}
```

At the beginning I have components, where each components is a one vertex of a graph with all it's edges. Then I create threads for each component in which I'm looking for the cheapest edge. Then I merge all the edges from minEdges into mst(final graph) and then collapse the components based on found edges. Same cykle with bigger components until there is one component left.

Problem is, that sometimes reference on component in `findPath` points on some place in memory and not the right component.

When I tried to debug it, it went all good, it pointed at right components and save minEdges perfectly as I wanted. But sometimes, even that in loop for creating threads I was pointing at right objects, in `findPath` it was pointing somewhere else, then it should and that was the segfault.

I would like to notice, that every thread is working with its own member of vector and also component is there just for reading, so it should be changed there ever. Also all components are correct before entering the threads and the sequential solution works fine.

Can anybody help me please? If you want to more info, I will add it.

Comment: You are unlikely to get help with the little information provided here. I advice you to to make your program go through different sanitizers/tools, "Clang sanitizers" and "Valgrind" comes to mind? ...Next use "locks" to get your code right before diving into `std::atomic_*`, the latter doesn't always imply "better performance" over locks.

Comment: Well, what other information would you like to know? I've run dr. Memory on this code and as I understood from it, I have leak at that place as I mentioned, I am pointing somewhere in memory not the corrent place.

Comment: You might reserve enough space in the vectors so that you aren't moving them around when they have to be resized.